How to use python package instead of curl when get & post both request to be done?
We have couple of rest calls for which we use curl system command. We want to move out of curl and use python modules to run those same curl commands how can we do?
Tried to convert to requests but could not convert --request POST option
    token_validate_cmd = ('curl --noproxy {1} \
    -H "Authorization: Basic {0}" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" \
    --request POST https://{1}/auth/v1/check \
    -d "grant_type=password&scope={2}&token={3}"'.format(some_key, some_url, scope, token))

How can we convert to python for above rest call instead of curl?

Review this https://www.w3schools.com/PYTHON/ref_requests_post.asp
